# React HOC and accessing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I am trying to understand the below React HOC;

```
const withSecretToLife = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class HOC extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          {...this.props}
          secretToLife={42}
        />
      );
    }
  }
    
  return HOC;
};

export default withSecretToLife;
```

And below is another component;

```
import withSecretToLife from 'components/withSecretToLife';

const DisplayTheSecret = props => (
  <div>
    The secret to life is {props.secretToLife}.
  </div>
);

const WrappedComponent = withSecretToLife(DisplayTheSecret);

export default WrappedComponent;
```

Specifically I am trying to understand

1. If it "DisplayTheSecret" that gets access to the prop "secretToLife" Or the WrappedComponent ? What is the correct way to look at this HOC ?
2. The line "const WrappedComponent = withSecretToLife(DisplayTheSecret);" is after the line "const DisplayTheSecret = props => ()". Is that a standard pattern and does it matter?
3. Related to above question, how are we able to do "props.secretToLife" before we even have the
   declaration/definition . for the WrappedComponent i.e. const
   WrappedComponent = withSecretToLife(DisplayTheSecret);
4. What is actually consumed/used in the above case say in App.js i.e `<WrappedComponent />` OR `<DisplayTheSecret />` OR either of them can be consumed ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You create a new component - `WrappedComponent`. It gets the prop
   `secretToLife`. `DisplayTheSecret` itself has no `secretToLife` prop.
2. In general practise, you should use variables that already has been
   defined above. So DisplayTheSecret should be defined above its
   usage. However, you can use it however you want as variables and functions are automatically hoisted to the top of the scope.
3. You are able to do it, but it might result in error at runtime. If
   you decide to use `DisplayTheSecret` component without wrapping it
   with `HOC`. `Typescript` solves these problems by generating typings
   during development.
4. `WrappedComponent` which consists of `DisplayTheSecret` and `HOC` composition.

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayTheSecret` is a simple component and it expects to find `secretToLife` among its properties.

`withSecretToLife` is a function that accepts `WrappedComponent` and returns another component (lets call it `WrappingHOC`)

`WrappingHOC` returns `WrappedComponent` passed to `withSecretToLife`, passes down all of its own props and adds a new one - `secretToLife`

`const WrappedComponent = withSecretToLife(DisplayTheSecret);` - this one is also called WrappedComponent, but it's not the same as `WrappedComponent` above (the one passed to the function), it is `WrappingHOC` with `DisplayTheSecret` let's call it `ResultingComponent`

So:

1. `secretToLife` is a property passed by `ResultingComponent` to `DisplayTheSecret`
2. The order does matter, it's always a good idea to declare a function before starting to use it
3. `secretToLife` is a normal property, you declare it when you create a component
4. `DisplayTheSecret` is not exported, so can't be consume outside of the module, apart from that it can be used without wrapping

Comment: Thanks a lot...yes, so on (4), since we are referring to "props.secretToLife" in DisplayTheSecret, it seems like we always expect the prop "secretToLife" and that would mean that it would always be called/referred via ResultingComponent (or WrappedComponent as per my code) AND not as DisplayTheSecret directly. Would that be correct ?
And that is also why we purposely "do not" export DisplayTheSecret, but instead we export ResultingComponent (or WrappedComponent)

So, essentially this comp would always be used/consumed, say in App.js, as <ResultingComponent /> and not <DisplayTheSecret />

Comment: There is no reason why you couldn't export DisplayTheSecret and provide the property when creating component, like <DisplayTheSecret secretToLife={63} />. The HOC in your example can only be useful if you have a number of different components that require secretToLife and you know you'll need to provide them 42 fairly often

Comment: Ok cool...so essentially, it seems like the purpose of the HOC function "withSecretToLife" in this case is to provide the prop "secretToLife" and this prop can be provided to any XYZ component that may need it...only thing we have to do is wrap this base/XYZ component with withSecretToLife and the resulting component (i.e. enhanced XYZ component) can just refer to "props.secretToLife" (this prop would be coming from the HOC)

Comment: Also as far as export is concerned, a bit unclear on that. So as you mentioned, there is nothing preventing us to do <DisplayTheSecret secretToLife={63} /> (assume this can be done only if we export DisplayTheSecret)...However, for practical purposes, when using HOC, it seems like the common pattern is to export the resulting component rather than the base component and we don't need to do pass secretToLife as.<ResultingComponent secretToLife={63} /> ...
Just doing <ResultingComponent /> should also give the proper prop value for secretToLife.

Comment: Yoy are correct. In practice a component is split into a HOC and wrapped part to reuse functionality (like fetching the same data from a db to present it in 2 different ways will be one HOC and 2 components that get this data from the HOC) and it rarely makes sense to export all individual pieces.

Comment: Ok cool...and is my understanding of invoking <ResultingComponent />  correct ? i.e. no need to explicitly pass props (secretToLife)

Comment: That's right, secretToLife is provided by the HOC, you don't need to provide it (and even if you do your value will be ignored)